# on the a.c.c. on radical ideals and the finite generation of radical ideals property of commutative rings with unity

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

For commutative rings, consider the following two  conditions :

1) ascending chain condition on radical ideals.

2) every radical ideal is finitely generated.

Does any of the conditions (1) or (2) imply the other for  commutative rings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(For commutative rings) $2\implies 1$ because having all radical ideals finitely generated implies all prime ideals are finitely generated, and the well-known theorem called [Cohen's theorem](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~reyes/cohenkaplansky.pdf) says this is an equivalent condition to being Noetherian, so it satisfies the ACC on *all* ideals.

On the other hand, the converse is false because it is easy to produce non Noetherian rings with a unique prime ideal: such a ring clearly satisfies 1 but not 2.  For example, take $V=\oplus_{i=1}^\infty F$ for a field $F$, and form the trivial extension $R=F(+)V$ with pointwise addition and multiplication given by $(a,v)(b,w)=(ab, aw+bv)$. Every subspace of $\{0\}(+)V$ is an ideal, so $R$ fails the ACC on ideals. This same ideal is the unique prime ideal of $R$, since it is both maximal and nilpotent.